# Cast type in mapping, FluentNhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I have this table where a few columns are set to types that I dont want. For instance.. a column named createDate that is set to a nvarchar(50).. which by default will be treated as a string..
But I dont want it to be mapped as a string, I want it to be mapped as a DateTime-object.
So how would I cast the string into a DateTime-object, during the mapping-process..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your mapping class is unaware of DataBase types. You can design your model with DateTime Properties and map those to the ill-typed Columns, hoping the conversion will work given the present format. I should also look up if it is possible to pass in a FormatString to parse against, if I were to try this without success.

```
public class Appointment
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}

public class AppointmentMap : ClassMap<Appointment>
{
    public AppointmentMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Start, "StartDateStringColumn");
        Map(x => x.End, "EndDateStringColumn");
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically your telling me that Nhibernate whould handle the parsing itself?..or?

Comment: Yes, NHibernate does the conversion automatically. At least, if the DateTime is stored as a String in ISO8601 Format, that is.